# Bootstrap3 upload file form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to program some jQuery/JavaScript to upload a file.

I have a `/upload` express upload api ready.  All I need is a form that will take in a few parameters, and generate a POST request.

I've tried using [JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) unsuccessfully. [Fileinput.js](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) didn't help either.

Can someone please please please help me in the right direction?

Here is a gist of the code I have written so far: https://gist.github.com/vasiliyb/1870864035ef327a83f7

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: everything from jade not being formatted properly, to not knowing how to tie a form to a javascript function.

Comment: I wish i knew how to simply tie this into a javascript funciton that uploaded a file :( http://codepen.io/bi11johnston/pen/bsGDf

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vasiliyb/c1866aec276c9baad4bc